# Conut only PP and AA

Tags: plsql

```
user_no  day_01  day_02   day_03  day_04 day_05  day_06
44       AA      PP PP    PP      PP     AA      PP
```

output

```
                         total(PP)
44 AA PP PP PP PP AA PP   5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` expressions on each day column and do a tally across all days:

```
SELECT user_no, day_01, day_02, day_03, day_04, day_05, day_06,
       (CASE WHEN day_01 IN ('PP', 'AA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN day_02 IN ('PP', 'AA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN day_03 IN ('PP', 'AA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN day_04 IN ('PP', 'AA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN day_05 IN ('PP', 'AA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN day_06 IN ('PP', 'AA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if the number of columns increases, you need to keep writing the case statement and the query may grow huge. I would use `Oracle 11g` functionality `UNPIVOT` and then count the occureance of 'P'. See below:

```
select count(col1) As P_COUNT
from 
(
WITH tbl (user_no,
          day_01,
          day_02,
          day_03,
          day_04,
          day_05,
          day_06,
          day_07)
     AS (SELECT '44', 'AA', 'PP', 'PP', 'PP', 'PP', 'AA', 'PP' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
 UNPIVOT ( 
            COL1 
            for COL2 in (user_no, day_01, day_02, day_03, day_04, day_05, day_06, day_07)            
         )
    ) z
  where z.col1 = 'PP'  ;
```

Output:

```
  P_COUNT
----------
         5
```